# After rendering an animation for 6h Blender 2.8 became extremely slow, any idea about the reason and a solution please?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, interface

After rendering a 150 frames animation for 6h, I have problems opening and editing files bigger than 10MB. Any idea about the reason and how to solve that problem would be welcome , thank you.

Comment: Sounds like a memory leak.  Check your system for memory hogs and restart those apps.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I closed all the apps, restarted the MacBook pro but to no avail...still extremely slow on opening the file (several minutes)...